# Is there a page listing all fields?

Tags: entities

I am wondering whether somebody has compiled a list of fields which are available for creating content types in Drupal. There are many lists of the most popular modules, but it would be great to have one focusing on existing fields, whether in core, or from third-party modules. I have looked around a bit, but always end up with lists of modules.

Answer (score 31):

There is a page at **admin/reports/fields** that lists the field name (the machine name), the field type and which module it came from, along with all of the bundles (content types, in the case of nodes) that use that field.

Comment: You might need to enable the module `field_ui` in order to see this page

Answer (score 23):

For Drupal 7, if you have [`drush`](http://drupal.org/project/drush), you can ask it for a list of "field types" (which includes their widgets), or "fields" (which includes the field name and its associated 'bundle').

The sample output (clean Drupal 7) for `drush field-info fields` gives for me:

```
 Field name    Field type               Bundles
 comment_body  text_long                comment_node_page,comment_node_article
 body          text_with_summary        page,article
 field_tags    taxonomy_term_reference  article
 field_image   image                    article
```

The output for `drush field-info types` gives:

```
 Field type             Default widget          Widgets
 file                   file_generic            file_generic
 image                  image_image             image_image
 list_integer           options_select          options_select, options_buttons
 list_float             options_select          options_select, options_buttons
 list_text              options_select          options_select, options_buttons
 list_boolean           options_buttons         options_buttons, options_onoff
 number_integer         number                  number
 number_decimal         number                  number
 number_float           number                  number
 taxonomy_term_referen  options_select          options_select,
 ce                                             options_buttons,
                                                taxonomy_autocomplete
 text                   text_textfield          text_textfield
 text_long              text_textarea           text_textarea
 text_with_summary      text_textarea_with_sum  text_textarea_with_summary
                        mary
```

Comment: Yes, thats a nice feature, thanks for sharing. I was hoping for a webpage somewhere. After creating a content type, I have now repeatedly run across fields, more or less by chance, which afforded me a function that I had been looking for earlier. So it would be nice to have sort of a "dictionary" web page, listing available fields.

Comment: A webpage would probably be static, and it would not contain all the possible fields; I am thinking to those fields that are automatically created from a module basing on some conditions, or those fields that are created from a user, such as a taxonomy term reference field.

Comment: drush version 6.0 commands are `drush field-info types` and `drush field-info fields`

Answer (score 4):

You could also install the "Devel" module, and use the "Development" Block. There's a menu link (devel/field/info) that shows a comprehensive list of all fields, instances, and bundles.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 6, just go to *admin/content/types/fields*.