# Drupal 7 Fields, when adding an existing field during content type creation, how to tell where else its used?

Tags: 7, entities

I just realized that if you use an existing field that is used in another content type and you change the field settings, you end up changing it on the other content types that share the same field. Is there a way to tell where else an existing field is being used?

Example: I have a field called "field_image" and using it in my basic page content type. Now I use it for my blog content type. How can I tell my basic page content type was using that same field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that information is easily accessible on the `/admin/reports/fields` page. It looks like this:

[image]

The first column is the field name, second is the field type, and the third is a list of bundles the field is currently attached to (with links to manage the fields).

Answer (score 1):

<s>There's no UI for this anymore.</s> The UI is in admin/reports/fields (h/t Clive)

Here's a good stack about how to find this info with drush:
[Is there a listing of Drupal fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15543/is-there-a-listing-of-drupal-fields)

Or you can grab it from the database:

```
SELECT entity_type, bundle FROM field_config_instance WHERE field_name = '$MY_FIELDNAME'
```

Comment: ;( thats not very easily accessible.

Comment: The UI is under the admin reports (where it's always been as far as I know)

Comment: Indeed! I never would have looked there. In Drupal 6 it was under admin/content/types/fields. Thanks, Clive.

Comment: Oh yeah it was somewhere else in Drupal 6, forgot about that :)