# field_data_field missing table

Tags: entities

I'm rebuilding (after Drupalgeddon) and I have a table that's gone missing... somehow.

It's being used to build Views displays for the homepage and so the homepage isn't loading at all. Which is obviously undesirable...

Error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'drupal.field_data_field_brief_summary' doesn't 
exist: 
SELECT t.* FROM {field_data_field_brief_summary} t 
WHERE
(entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) 
AND (entity_id IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1, 
:db_condition_placeholder_2, :db_condition_placeholder_3)) 
AND (language IN (:db_condition_placeholder_4)) 
AND (deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_5) 
ORDER BY delta ASC; Array ( 
[:db_condition_placeholder_0] => node 
[:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1026 
[:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 1051 
[:db_condition_placeholder_3] => 1095 
[:db_condition_placeholder_4] => und 
[:db_condition_placeholder_5] => 0 ) 
in field_sql_storage_field_storage_load() 
(line 392 of C:\projects\drupal\modules\field
\modules\field_sql_storage\field_sql_storage.module).
```

I used the Drush field listing function as described here [Is there a listing of Drupal fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15543/is-there-a-listing-of-drupal-fields) or more specifically, the `drush field-info fields` command in the comment below the chosen answer. Which displays, amongst many others:

```
field_brief_summary    text_long
```

So I think it's there. But the tables `field_data_field_brief_summary` and `field_revision_field_brief_summary` are clearly not in the database when I check.

What does on do in this situation? I need field_data_field_brief_summary (and version) back, and I have a copy of it in the version I'm using to rebuild from, but it should be there and I'm wary of trusting that I can just use a MySQL statement to CREATE and INSERT INTO when it's something implicit in the Drupal CMS.

Comment: If your table is missing, do you expect there can be any other solution than to restore it from backup?

Comment: Yes, after all I didn't delete it - so my assumption is that a mysterious process removed it for me. I tried registry rebuild too, but that's not brought it back. I should say I am currently trying to do a MySQL CREATE and INSERT INTO

Comment: But whatever deleted it, MySQL does not support any kind of undelete. If it's not there, it is not there, simple as that. Either you have backups, or you have a problem.

Comment: OK, but I just didn't want to interfere with any Drupal function that I'm unaware of and cause further problems. I have backups, so fortunately I *hope* I don't have a problem.

Comment: @ja_him Don.t do the direct operations in mysql.

Comment: Restoring single table from backups will interfere less than using your site with said table missing... usually. It is difficult and broad topic. If you can, take snapshots of your site during the process.

Comment: Yes and I suspected it would be, Molot and thanks - I will do. Why can I not do the operations direct in MySQL, program?

Comment: Might be wrong but I don't think @Mołot is suggesting you can't use MySQL directly here. In fact you pretty much have to, Drupal won't be able to help much

Comment: @Clive it was [program](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/26613/program) who suggested not to use MySQL directly, not me. And I don't know why he said that. I agree it will probably be necessity to use MySQL in direct way here. By the way, do you have idea how to write an *answer* to this question? Because all I can think of are mere suggestions.

Comment: If I had time I'd probably write up a brief note about the structure of field data/revision tables, and suggest either recreating manually or with a `SELECT INTO` statement @Mołot. Definitely answerable IMO

Comment: @Clive I agree it is answerable, all I'm saying is that *I* had no idea how. I'll try if I'll find enough time to do it right.